# Милиционер, но полицейский

Tags: словообразование

Как известно, сотрудник милиции называется милиционер, но при этом сотрудник полиции почему-то полицейский. Слова однотипные, но образуются по-разному. При этом логично было бы предположить, что слово "полиция" более... западное, но форма "полицейский" как раз образуется по-русски в виде прилагательного (как, например, пожарный). Однако все вышло наоборот.
По какому принципу образованы названия этих профессий и почему тут нет единообразция? Почему не "милицейский" или не "полиционер"?

Comment: повтор
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/20795

Comment: Это НЕ повтор вопроса, и прощу не своевольничать на форуме.  
Администрация.

Comment: ОК
Но это дейстие не является своевольчанием.)))
Ибо законно)))

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, соглашусь с behemothus'ом, в этом вопросе другая формулировка того же самого вопроса. И просьба разъяснить, что вы понимаете, под своевольничаем, потому что форум со свободным редактированием и любой пользователь с рейтингом от 3000 имеет право закрывать вопросы, а любой у кого есть хотя бы 500 баллов эти вопросы переоткрывать.

И ещё, если не секрет, на каком основании ответ @Tagirix'а отмечен как правильный? На вопрос он не отвечает и вообще за исключением первого предложения, там почему-то рассуждения об английском языке, а не о русском.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, слово «Милицейский» существует (вспомните радио «Милицейская волна). В английском языке, насколько я знаю, нет отдельного прилагательного, образованного от существительное *Police*. Я где-то встречал что-то вроде «Police Department» (Полицейский департамент или родительным падежом «Департамент полиции»).

Про «Полиционер» тоже что-то было.

Кстати, «Бобби» — разговорная лексема в английском языке, при помощи которой англичане именуют полицейских.